# + sign not inserted to Oracle db

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am trying to insert data with the query

```
UPDATE CONTACTS SET internationalmsisdn = +904562038544 WHERE id = 31328
```

After executing query, the `internationalmsisdn` column is shown as `904562038544`.
Why do I lost `+` sign ?

Any idea?

Comment: Data type. 'single quote'.

Comment: What is the datatype of internationalmsisdn?  What are you using to look at the data after you update the record?

Comment: `number` columns don't store the `+` sign. You need to apply a formatting when you *display* the data, e.g. `to_char(904562038544, 'S999999999999')`. If the `+` is indeed a *required* part of your data, you need to store this value in a `varchar` column (with all the disadvantages that using the wrong data type brings with it). Even better: format your number in your Java code using a `SimpelDateFormat`. Formatting for display does not belong into the SQL layer. It's the responsibility of the application.

Comment: one more time ! What is you column data type ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To insert a special character as a string you need to have the column type as `varchar` and pass the values as ,

```
UPDATE CONTACTS SET internationalmsisdn = '+904562038544' WHERE id = 31328
```

Hope this helps !!

Comment: when I use '+904562038544', no difference

Comment: I am using jdbc, is there any relation jdbc and this problem?

Comment: <facepalm> @Poyraz, you need the column type to be a string type like varchar2, as san krish said.